# How does author derives $\nabla_i V_{ij} = \nabla_{ij} V_{ij} = - \nabla_j V_{ji}$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-derivative, classical-mechanics

In the book of *Classical Mechanics* by Golstein, at page 11, it is given that

> When the forces are all conservative, the second term in Eq. (1.29) can be rewritten as a sum over *pairs* of particles, the terms for each pair being of the form
>   $$
> -\int_1^2(\nabla_i V_{ij} \cdot d{\bf s}_i + \nabla_j V_{ij} \cdot d{\bf s}_j)
> $$
>   If the difference vector ${\bf r}_i - {\bf r}_j$ is denoted by ${\bf r}_{ij}$ and $\nabla_{ij}$ stands for the gradient with respect to ${\bf r}_{ij}$, then
>   $$\nabla_i V_{ij} = \nabla_{ij} V_{ij} = - \nabla_j V_{ji}$$

However, I cannot understand how does the author concludes the equality

$$\nabla_i V_{ij} = \nabla_{ij} V_{ij} = - \nabla_j V_{ji}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the potential $V_{ij}$ depends on the difference ${\bf x}_{ij} = {\bf x}_i - {\bf x}_j$, so

$$
\frac{\partial V_{ij}}{\partial {\bf x}_j} = 
\frac{\partial {\bf x}_{ij}}{\partial {\bf x}_j} \frac{\partial V_{ij}}{\partial {\bf x}_{ij}}
= \frac{\partial ({\bf x}_i - {\bf x}_j)}{\partial {\bf x}_j} \frac{\partial V_{ij}}{\partial {\bf x}_{ij}} = 
-\frac{\partial V_{ij}}{\partial {\bf x}_{ij}}
$$

Similarly

$$
\frac{\partial V_{ij}}{\partial {\bf x}_i} = +\frac{\partial V_{ij}}{\partial {\bf x}_{ij}}
$$

Or in Goldstein's notation

$$
\nabla_i V_{ij} = \nabla_{ij} V_{ij} = -\nabla_j V_{ij}
$$

Comment: Thanks both for the answer and the edit to the question.

Comment: @onurcanbektas Happy to help